# Is the word tenfold a misnomer?

Tags: etymology

The dictionary definition is

> ten times as great or as much

I believe that this is a misnomer. The word seems to describe a process of folding something ten times; for example, a piece of paper. If you fold a piece of paper ten times you will get 2<sup>10</sup> or 1024 different rectangles.

I don't understand how the definition of this word came to be and how is it different from the phrase *ten times*?

Comment: It's the same as 'ten times', just another way of saying it.

Comment: Even if your assumption about the etymology were right (which it isn't: see @choster's answer), it would be irrelevant. A word means what it means, not what somebody thinks it ought to mean. Meanings do change (and it sometimes happens that different people use a word in inconsistent ways), but it is extremely rare that an individual is able to effect a change in the meaning of a word.

Comment: Question assumes the only way to fold a piece of paper ten times is to double it each time. The folding of cloth, as the etymology suggests, refers to pleats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suffix *-fold* is not in any way related to the word *fold* in modern English. It is a way of indicating a multiplicative product, except in the word *manifold* which is indefinitely numerous.

Etymonline says

> **-fold**:  multiplicative suffix, from O.E. *-feald*, related to O.N. *-faldr*; Ger. *-falt*; Goth. *falþs*; Gk. *-paltos*, *-plos*; L. *-plus*.
>
> **fold** (v.): O.E. *faldan* (Mercian), *fealdan* (W.Saxon), transitive, "to bend cloth back over itself" …. Related: *Folded*; *folding*. The noun meaning "a bend or ply in anything" is mid-13c., from the verb.

Comment: On the contrary, they _are_ related, but a long way back.

Comment: Yes, both root and affix come from the PIE root _*pel³_, glossed as 'fold' in the _AHD of PIE Roots_. Any online etymology source that doesn't cite PIE roots isn't worth the electrons it's written in.

Comment: Very well then, edited. I didn't realize this was *Old* EL&U :).